# How to send daily Confluence reports /JIRA dashboard in email using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jira, confluence

I have requirement to grab details from either JIRA Dashboard or Confluence Page and send it it in daily status report to selected recipients. I just wanted to understand if this can be done using Jenkins as in sending daily status report

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can get details from JIRA or Confluence using a script or other prefered method. If that's possible you can send the details to selected recipients as a email.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).